# É possível utilizar Tiles dentro de tags do SpringMVC?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, apache-tiles

Olá, estou criando um formulário genérico de modo que possa parametrizar alguns atributos. Quero fazer o seguinte :

```
<sf:form cssClass="form" modelAttribute="<tiles:getAsString name="modelAttribute"/>" action="<tiles:getAsString name="action"/>" />
```

Quando faço isso porém, ao carregar a tela recebo a seguinte exceção:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /forma-page.jsp (line: 4, column: 81) equal symbol expected
```

quando eu não utilizo a tag específica do spring, o código funciona. Gostaria de utilizar dessa forma para poder fazer validações usando BeanValidation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não é possível fazer isso.

Claro que algumas vezes misturamos uma tag JSP com uma tag HTML, mas não dá para colocar uma tag JSP dentro de outra tag JSP.

Uma forma de resolver isso é disponibilizar os atributes do template como atributos dentro do JSP e depois usá-los normalmente na taglib do Spring ou em qualquer outra.

Um exemplo de como fazer isso ([extraído da documentação](https://tiles.apache.org/framework/tutorial/advanced/list-attributes.html)):

```xml
<%@ taglib uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix="tiles" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles-extras" prefix="tilesx" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt" prefix="c" %>
<tilesx:useAttribute id="list" name="items" classname="java.util.List" />
<c:forEach var="item" items="${list}">
  ...
</c:forEach>
```

No exemplo acima, a tag `tilesx:useAttribute` faz com que o atributo de nome `items` seja disponibilizado no escopo do JSP como `list`. A lista então é usada no loop usando *expression language*.

Comment: Otima resposta. Obrigado!